# How to copy columns name from a list(form) to a library using SPD 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, list-form, json

I have a form in SPD which has 2 columns PM & DM , how will i copy same column names from the form to library using javascript JSON so that on form submits the library column name automatically fills up with an item(attachment i have put) and those columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you designed the form in SPD, but if you build an InfoPath form, you can promote the field to surface them in the list view in SharePoint. 
Here's a step by step guide for building forms with InfoPath. 
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2121642